# Удаление ячейки из таблицы при нажатие на кнопку UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, delete

У меня такой вопрос:
Есть ViewController на котором расположена таблица. Она заполняется из CoreData с этим все в порядке. Мне нужно реализовать удаление ячейки при нажатие на кнопку в правом углу ячейки.

Знаю как реализовать удаление при свайпе, но это не то. Нужно именно при нажатие. Искал подобную проблему, но что-то не нашел, извеняюсь если повтор.
Как это можно сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так, а в чем разница со свайпом? И там и там решение примерно одинаковое. Удаляете нужный объект из коллекции, ищите и удаляете связанную с ним ячейку либо через tableView.deleteRows, либо вызываете reloadData для пересчета всей таблицы.

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {    
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "your_cell", for: indexPath) as! YurCell
  cell.delete_button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(delete), for: .touchUpInside)
  return cell
}

@objc func delete(_ sender: UIButton) {
   //ваш код для удаления
}
```